# Setting map bounds for multiple markers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

I am trying to set bounds for a group of markers, but keep getting an entire earth map. I have checked and all my markers have proper coordinates set. Here's my code in it's entirety:

PHP

```
foreach ($business AS $b) {
        $mapData .= '["'.$b->name.'", '.$b->lat.', '.$b->lon.', '.$cnt++.', '.($b->ID != '' ? 1 : 0).'],';
        $avgLat = $avgLat + $b->lat;
        $avgLon = $avgLon + $b->lon;
        $cntEnrolled = $cntEnrolled +1;
    }
}

$mapData = rtrim($mapData, ",");
$avgLat = $avgLat / $cntEnrolled;
$avgLon = $avgLon / $cntEnrolled;
```

HTML

```
<div id="map" class="pad0 mar0 w100p"></div>
```

JS

```
<script>                      
    function initMap() {
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            center: {
                lat: '.$avgLat.', 
                lng: '.$avgLon.'
            }
          });                        
          setMarkers(map);
    }
      
    var restaurants = ['.$mapData.'];
        
    function setMarkers(map) {
        
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();            
          
        for (var i = 0; i < restaurants.length; i++) {
            var restaurant = restaurants[i];
            var layerposit = (restaurant[4] == 1 ? 999  : restaurant[3]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {
                    lat: restaurant[1], 
                    lng: restaurant[2]
                },
                map: map,           
                title: restaurant[0],
                zIndex: layerposit
            });
            bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBQo-k5Tta6adY9AuEi1afno8HKvac_WoQ&callback=initMap"></script>
```

And here's what is rendered:
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: where are you defining $avglat and $avglon ?

Comment: The posted code works for me (with the data you provided) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1baz7uhw/1/).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Updated post. @zipzit I get avg after I build an array with PHP.

Comment: @geocodezip I am stuck. It looks right but the results are killing me. Can't figure out what possibly could be the issue...

Comment: Please provide the data that causes it to exhibit the issue.  You can see in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1baz7uhw/1/) the subset of the data you posted doesn't exhibit the problem (or a link to your site that doesn't work).

Comment: @geocodezip  I noticed in your code CSS part. On my site the body has the following: margin-bottom: 70px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 80px;

Comment: I tried putting the same CSS and although It messed with my layout it did not help the map rendering. So weird...

Comment: The CSS is not relevant to your question.

Comment: [the data you posted in the comments still doesn't exhibit the issue (updated fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1baz7uhw/2/) (BTW- you should [edit] your question to update it to address comments, it is really hard to read/use code from comments).  Are there any interesting warnings/errors in the javascript console?

Comment: I build another page and moved my code there, while on the same site but in different section and everything works as expected. I think I need to figure out what's causing the other layout cause such havoc. Thanks for your help, really.

Comment: Where is the page that **doesn't** work?

Comment: It's a password protected admin page. It uses a slightly different layout and I'll have to poke around there to figure out what's causing such mess.

Comment: You sure you don't have one (or more) sets of coordinates backwards?

Comment: The map that works fine uses exactly same data and code. It's gotta be something in the alternative layout.

Comment: @geocodezip -- I figured it out and posted the answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was the following class withing bootstrap tabs: **.tab-pane**

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="mymap">
```

Take it out and all the map issues go away.